# Beautiful soup findall not returning all the results

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to **scrape** ball by ball data of a cricket match using `find_all` in `BeautifulSoup`. The code is :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/10904/commentary/1075502/south-africa-vs-bangladesh-1st-test-bangladesh-tour-of-sa-2017-18'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
comment = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "over-circle")
print(len(comment))
print(comment[22])
```

I read answers to previous questions regarding this issue and almost all refer to using different html parser. I have tried `lxml, html.parser, html5lib` but none of them above mentioned (which were mostly recommended in previous questions) seem to give any different result.
The no. of balls is shown to be 23 whereas it should be much more. Output:

```
23
<div class="over-circle low-score" data-reactid="463"><span class="over-score" data-reactid="464">0</span></div>
```

Comment: Going to the URL and running `document.querySelectorAll('div.over-circle').length` gives me 23. Are you sure there should be more?

Comment: If you will inspect the webpage, you will find a lot more div for this class. There should be one for each ball bowled. One thing I noticed is that initially it shows only 23 divs as shown above. However more appear when we scroll down(they are not loaded initially). Is that causing a problem?

Comment: @Arohan Ajit the data is dynamically generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is dynamic so it's not all rendered. You can go straigh to the source and pull in the json response, which also includes the total number of pages. Once you have the total number of pages, you can iterate through those using the query parameters, add that from each previous page to get a final output of all the data.

I don't know exactly what data you're interested in, but it's all there. I converted it to a dataframe, but you can do what you'd like with the json structure:

It is nested however. The `athletesInvolved` columns consists of a listed dictionary. You can still normalize/flatten that out too if needed (let me know if you would like that done too, it's rather easy to do), but will obviously then increase the number of rows/columns.

```
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/cricket/10904/playbyplay'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'contentorigin': 'espn',
'event': '1075502',
'page': '1',
'period': '4',
'section': 'cricinfo'}

# Get inital page of data, including total number of pages to iterate through
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
pageCount = response['commentary']['pageCount']

print ('Total pages: %s\nProcessed page: 1' %(pageCount))


# Store the initial page to jsonData, iterate through the next `pageCount` pages and add that to the list for a final result
jsonData = response
for page in range(2, pageCount+1):
    payload = {
            'contentorigin': 'espn',
            'event': '1075502',
            'page': page,
            'period': '4',
            'section': 'cricinfo'}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

    jsonData['commentary']['items'] = jsonData['commentary']['items'] + response['commentary']['items']
    print ('Processed page: %s' %page)



df = json_normalize(jsonData['commentary']['items'])
```

**Output: sample of first 5 rows out of 198 rows**

```
print (df.head(5).to_string())
                                    athletesInvolved awayScore batsman.athlete.displayName batsman.athlete.fullName batsman.athlete.id batsman.athlete.name batsman.athlete.shortName  batsman.faced  batsman.fours  batsman.runs  batsman.sixes batsman.team.abbreviation batsman.team.displayName batsman.team.id batsman.team.name  batsman.totalRuns bowler.athlete.displayName bowler.athlete.fullName bowler.athlete.id bowler.athlete.name bowler.athlete.shortName  bowler.balls  bowler.conceded  bowler.maidens  bowler.overs bowler.team.abbreviation bowler.team.displayName bowler.team.id bowler.team.name  bowler.wickets  clock              date dismissal.batsman.athlete.displayName dismissal.batsman.athlete.fullName dismissal.batsman.athlete.id dismissal.batsman.athlete.name dismissal.batsman.athlete.shortName  dismissal.bowled dismissal.bowler.athlete.displayName dismissal.bowler.athlete.fullName dismissal.bowler.athlete.id dismissal.bowler.athlete.name dismissal.bowler.athlete.shortName  dismissal.dismissal  dismissal.minutes dismissal.retiredText                                    dismissal.text dismissal.type homeScore   id  innings.ballLimit  innings.balls  innings.byes  innings.day  innings.fallOfWickets innings.id  innings.legByes  innings.noBalls  innings.number  innings.remainingBalls  innings.remainingOvers innings.remainingRuns  innings.runRate  innings.runs  innings.session  innings.target  innings.totalRuns  innings.wickets  innings.wides  mediaId otherBatsman.athlete.displayName otherBatsman.athlete.fullName otherBatsman.athlete.id otherBatsman.athlete.name otherBatsman.athlete.shortName  otherBatsman.faced  otherBatsman.fours  otherBatsman.runs  otherBatsman.sixes otherBatsman.team.abbreviation otherBatsman.team.displayName otherBatsman.team.id otherBatsman.team.name  otherBatsman.totalRuns otherBowler.athlete.displayName otherBowler.athlete.fullName otherBowler.athlete.id otherBowler.athlete.name otherBowler.athlete.shortName  otherBowler.balls  otherBowler.conceded  otherBowler.maidens  otherBowler.overs otherBowler.team.abbreviation otherBowler.team.displayName otherBowler.team.id otherBowler.team.name  otherBowler.wickets  over.actual  over.ball  over.balls  over.byes  over.complete  over.legByes  over.limit  over.maiden  over.noBall  over.number  over.overs  over.runs  over.unique  over.wickets  over.wide  period   periodText playType.description playType.id postText                                            preText  scoreValue  sequence                        shortText speedKPH speedMPH team.abbreviation team.displayName team.id   team.name                                               text
0  [{'id': '56194', 'name': 'Tamim Iqbal', 'short...         0                 Tamim Iqbal         Tamim Iqbal Khan              56194          Tamim Iqbal                     Tamim              1              0             0              0                     BDESH               Bangladesh              25        Bangladesh                  0               Morne Morkel            Morne Morkel             46538        Morne Morkel                   Morkel             1                0               0           0.1                       SA            South Africa              3     South Africa               0  00:00  2017-09-28T10:00                           Tamim Iqbal                   Tamim Iqbal Khan                        56194                    Tamim Iqbal                               Tamim             False                         Morne Morkel                      Morne Morkel                       46538                  Morne Morkel                             Morkel                False                  0                                                                     NaN                        0  410                  0              1             0            4                      0     199062                0                0               4                       0                     0.0                   424              0.0             0                2             424                  0                0              0        0                      Imrul Kayes                   Imrul Kayes                  280734               Imrul Kayes                          Imrul                   0                   0                  0                   0                          BDESH                    Bangladesh                   25             Bangladesh                       0                             NaN                          NaN                    NaN                      NaN                           NaN                  0                     0                    0                NaN                           NaN                          NaN                 NaN                   NaN                    0          0.1          1           6          0          False             0         0.0            1            0            1         0.1          0         0.01             2          0       4  4th innings               no run           2           <b>2.25pm</b> South Africa gather into a huddl...           0    400001    Morkel to Tamim Iqbal, no run  138.452   86.030             BDESH       Bangladesh      25  Bangladesh  fullish length ball, angled in from wide of th...
1  [{'id': '56194', 'name': 'Tamim Iqbal', 'short...         0                 Tamim Iqbal         Tamim Iqbal Khan              56194          Tamim Iqbal                     Tamim              2              0             0              0                     BDESH               Bangladesh              25        Bangladesh                  0               Morne Morkel            Morne Morkel             46538        Morne Morkel                   Morkel             2                0               0           0.2                       SA            South Africa              3     South Africa               0  00:00  2017-09-28T10:00                           Tamim Iqbal                   Tamim Iqbal Khan                        56194                    Tamim Iqbal                               Tamim             False                         Morne Morkel                      Morne Morkel                       46538                  Morne Morkel                             Morkel                False                  0                                                                     NaN                        0  420                  0              2             0            4                      0     199062                0                0               4                       0                     0.0                   424              0.0             0                2             424                  0                0              0        0                      Imrul Kayes                   Imrul Kayes                  280734               Imrul Kayes                          Imrul                   0                   0                  0                   0                          BDESH                    Bangladesh                   25             Bangladesh                       0                             NaN                          NaN                    NaN                      NaN                           NaN                  0                     0                    0                NaN                           NaN                          NaN                 NaN                   NaN                    0          0.2          2           6          0          False             0         0.0            1            0            1         0.2          0         0.02             2          0       4  4th innings               no run           2                                                                       0    400002    Morkel to Tamim Iqbal, no run  135.891   84.439             BDESH       Bangladesh      25  Bangladesh  length ball outside off, Tamim stands tall and...
2  [{'id': '56194', 'name': 'Tamim Iqbal', 'short...         0                 Tamim Iqbal         Tamim Iqbal Khan              56194          Tamim Iqbal                     Tamim              3              0             0              0                     BDESH               Bangladesh              25        Bangladesh                  0               Morne Morkel            Morne Morkel             46538        Morne Morkel                   Morkel             3                0               0           0.3                       SA            South Africa              3     South Africa               0  00:00  2017-09-28T10:00                           Tamim Iqbal                   Tamim Iqbal Khan                        56194                    Tamim Iqbal                               Tamim             False                         Morne Morkel                      Morne Morkel                       46538                  Morne Morkel                             Morkel                False                  0                                                                     NaN                        0  430                  0              3             0            4                      0     199062                0                0               4                       0                     0.0                   424              0.0             0                2             424                  0                0              0        0                      Imrul Kayes                   Imrul Kayes                  280734               Imrul Kayes                          Imrul                   0                   0                  0                   0                          BDESH                    Bangladesh                   25             Bangladesh                       0                             NaN                          NaN                    NaN                      NaN                           NaN                  0                     0                    0                NaN                           NaN                          NaN                 NaN                   NaN                    0          0.3          3           6          0          False             0         0.0            1            0            1         0.3          0         0.03             2          0       4  4th innings               no run           2           Zahi: "The six went for four? Last ball needs ...           0    400003    Morkel to Tamim Iqbal, no run  140.489   87.296             BDESH       Bangladesh      25  Bangladesh  fullish, comes into Tamim who flicks it to mid...
3  [{'id': '56194', 'name': 'Tamim Iqbal', 'short...         0                 Tamim Iqbal         Tamim Iqbal Khan              56194          Tamim Iqbal                     Tamim              4              0             0              0                     BDESH               Bangladesh              25        Bangladesh                  0               Morne Morkel            Morne Morkel             46538        Morne Morkel                   Morkel             4                0               0           0.4                       SA            South Africa              3     South Africa               1  00:00  2017-09-28T10:00                           Tamim Iqbal                   Tamim Iqbal Khan                        56194                    Tamim Iqbal                               Tamim              True                         Morne Morkel                      Morne Morkel                       46538                  Morne Morkel                             Morkel                 True                  2                        Tamim Iqbal  b Morkel 0 (2m 4b 0x4 0x6) SR: 0.00         bowled         0  440                  0              4             0            4                      1     199062                0                0               4                       0                     0.0                   424              0.0             0                2             424                  0                1              0        0                      Imrul Kayes                   Imrul Kayes                  280734               Imrul Kayes                          Imrul                   0                   0                  0                   0                          BDESH                    Bangladesh                   25             Bangladesh                       0                             NaN                          NaN                    NaN                      NaN                           NaN                  0                     0                    0                NaN                           NaN                          NaN                 NaN                   NaN                    0          0.4          4           6          0          False             0         0.0            1            0            1         0.4          0         0.04             2          0       4  4th innings                  out           9                                                                       0    400004       Morkel to Tamim Iqbal, OUT  136.028   84.524             BDESH       Bangladesh      25  Bangladesh  bowled him! Morkel strikes first over the chas...
4  [{'id': '373696', 'name': 'Mominul Haque', 'sh...         0               Mominul Haque            Mominul Haque             373696        Mominul Haque                   Mominul              1              0             0              0                     BDESH               Bangladesh              25        Bangladesh                  0               Morne Morkel            Morne Morkel             46538        Morne Morkel                   Morkel             5                0               0           0.5                       SA            South Africa              3     South Africa               1  00:00  2017-09-28T10:00                         Mominul Haque                      Mominul Haque                       373696                  Mominul Haque                             Mominul             False                         Morne Morkel                      Morne Morkel                       46538                  Morne Morkel                             Morkel                False                  0                                                                     NaN                        0  450                  0              5             0            4                      0     199062                0                0               4                       0                     0.0                   424              0.0             0                2             424                  0                1              0        0                      Imrul Kayes                   Imrul Kayes                  280734               Imrul Kayes                          Imrul                   0                   0                  0                   0                          BDESH                    Bangladesh                   25             Bangladesh                       0                             NaN                          NaN                    NaN                      NaN                           NaN                  0                     0                    0                NaN                           NaN                          NaN                 NaN                   NaN                    0          0.5          5           6          0          False             0         0.0            1            0            1         0.5          0         0.05             2          0       4  4th innings               no run           2                                                                       0    400005  Morkel to Mominul Haque, no run  139.982   86.981             BDESH       Bangladesh      25  Bangladesh  <b>huge appeal for a leg before</b>. Not out s...
```

Answer (score 0):

You've guessed it right. Not all data is loaded at once (hence, You see only what's initially loaded). You could implement additional logic that will loop until program reaches last page.

Here's the URL of one of the data pages: `https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/cricket/10904/playbyplay?contentorigin=espn&event=1075502&page=6&period=4&section=cricinfo` You will need to increase `page` param until You keep getting valid data.

If You examine response of this URL, You'll see that this is JSON file with additional 24 items.